# How to create custom index writer for Apache Nutch 2.x?

Tags: apache, plugins, configuration, nutch

I'm looking a way to create custom index writer for Apache Nutch. Which config file should I edit and what kind of properties I should add there?

I couldn't find anything useful from conf/nutch-default.xml

Answer (score -1):

You will have to write your custom plugin and then configure the nutch to use your custom plugin.

Following link will give you step by step procedure to achieve this task:

***http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/WritingPluginExample***

Comment: Does this work also on nutch 2.x series? Since the link says: Start by downloading the Nutch-1.3 source code.